# Shell script calling rows from text document

Tags: bash, shell, awk, rename, mv

I need some help with files renaming.
At start I prepare text file : names.txt
This file contain:

```
T22.tsv
T33.tsv
T101.tsv
T48.tsv
```

Names of files at start in the folder /home/filip/Desktop/

```
Xpress33.tsv
Xpress5.tsv
Xpress12.tsv
Xpress006.tsv
```

Names of files after mv at /home/filip/Desktop/:

```
T22.tsv
T33.tsv
T101.tsv
T48.tsv
```

Could you help, how could I read from the text file in bash script, it could be with awk.
I tried :

```
A= awk 'NR==1 {print $0}' names.txt 
mv Xpress33.tsv   "$A"
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to store the output of a command into a variable. For this, you need the syntax `var=$(command)`.

Hence, this should make:

```
A=$(awk 'NR==1 {print $0}' names.txt)
mv Xpress33.tsv "$A"
```

Note also that these are equivalent, because `{print $0}` is the default behaviour of `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $0}' names.txt
awk 'NR==1' names.txt
```

If you want to make it even more direct, you can do:

```
mv Xpress33.tsv "$(awk 'NR==1' names.txt)"
```

Comment: I strongly suspect this is one of those cases where we've helped the OP implement a bad solution to whatever his real problem is because this makes zero sense. IF he really just wanted to use the first line from a file as a target file name for a move he could just do `mv source "$(head -1 file)"` or even a simple `read`. I bet this is a hack in the middle of a muddy script.

Comment: @FilipZembol is everything fine? I don't know why you unaccepted the answer.

Comment: Sorry it was mistake, I only thinking about loop for this and when I read your answer, I accidentally click on the flag.

Comment: No problem! Also, consider checking what @EdMorton comments, because probably your problem is broader and you could approach it differently. Cheers!